# Take string value to textview from another java class

Tags: android

Here I have Android project which can capture incoming call phone number.
In PhoneStateReceiver.java I have string called incomingNumber. I need to print the value of ***incomingNumber*** to TextView called ***numberView*** in activity_main.xml.

**PhoneStateReceiver.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
        try {

            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Ringing State Number is - " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:id="@+id/numberView"
     />
```

And below show my other manifest.xml & MainActivity.java files for your reference.

**manifest.xml**

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        //integrating Broadcast Receiver to our project.
        <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    //take permission from the users
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to create BroadcastReceiver for particular activity.

Comment: yes i already create BroadcastReceiver on PhoneStateReceiver.java file as shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView numberView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    numberView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberView);
    registerReceiver(tripMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("msg"));

}

private final BroadcastReceiver tripMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WakeLocker.acquire(context);
        Log.i("no", getIntent().getStringExtra("no"));
numberView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("no"));
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(tripMessageReceiver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
}



public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
    try {

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
Intent intentBroadCast;
            intentBroadCast = new Intent("msg");
            intentBroadCast.putExtra("no", incomingNumber);
            context.sendBroadcast(intentBroadCast);
            Toast.makeText(context,"Ringing State Number is - " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}    
}

public abstract class WakeLocker {
private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

@SuppressLint("Wakelock")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void acquire(Context context) {
    if (wakeLock != null)
        wakeLock.release();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
}

public static void release() {
    if (wakeLock != null)
        wakeLock.release();
    wakeLock = null;
}}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />//add permission in menifest file
```

BroadcastReceiver for particular activity